# Android Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 in openRawResource

Tags: android, exception, resources

i got this error from a google play user:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1010)
at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:935)
```

The application works on the emulator, on my phone and many other phones. I don't know why this user get the error. The code that generates the error is:

```
//The getTag will get the R.drawable.imagename
String varia= imageView1.getTag().toString(); 
TypedValue returnedValue = new TypedValue();

try {
myNum = Integer.parseInt(varia);
} 
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {}

getResources().openRawResource(myNum, returnedValue);
```

The openrawResource looks to not work.

The tag contains the resource name: R.drawable.imagename

I repeat: this code normally works, i don't know why this user got the error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How do you set the tag for imageView1?
The error might occur when `myNum = Integer.parseInt(varia);` throws an exception. In this case `getResources().openRawResource(myNum, returnedValue);` will attempt to get a resource with ID 0.

Comment: The tag contains the resource name: R.drawable.imagename